# How to load choices for one of form_extra_fields in ModelView dynamically during serving data for rendering?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have an `User` admin *ModelView* with *form_extra_field* `constituency` and I wanted to have it dynamically loaded *choices* (it is *SelectField*). Model for this view is `User` which will store constituency as `id` of the item.

I tried to load *choices* from remote API but certainly it was wrong time to load these things because of **RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.** It happened at migration command `...venv/bin/flask db init -d ctiweb/migrations` . I read some API_KEY from config object which needs to have application context ...

So solution would be load choices at *serving* or *rendering* time. I don't want have the solutiont in customized template rather I want it in customized admin *ModelView* for `User` model.

Is there such a solution? Can I overload somemethod of ModelView which has application context already (so it is during serving data or rendering template)?

part of source code from `models.py`

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    is_superuser = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    constituency_id = db.Column(db.Integer())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError("not readable attribute")

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

part of source code from `admin.py`

```py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class UserAdminModelView(ModelView):

    def serve_constituency_choices():
        consituencies = (
            get_constituency(constituency_id) for constituency_id in get_constituencies()
        )
        return ((constituency['id'], constituency['name']) for constituency in consituencies)

    column_list = ['username', 'email', 'is_superuser']
    form_columns = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'constituency']
    form_extra_fields = {
        'password': PasswordField('Password'),
        'constituency': SelectField('Constituency', choices=serve_constituency_choices())
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, but I cannot mark the answer as the winner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have finally find a *simpler* solution - only with class iterator on constituency choices. I think is better than the first one :-)

```py
class ConstituencyChoices(Iterator):
    def __init__(self, first_item=None):
        self.first_item = first_item
        self.constituencies = None

    def __next__(self):
        if self.first_item is not None:
            res = self.first_item
            self.first_item = None
            return res
        if self.constituencies is None:
            self.constituencies = (
                get_constituency(constituency_id) for constituency_id in get_constituencies()
            )
        constituency = self.constituencies.__next__()
        res = (constituency['id'], constituency['name'])
        return res

# pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
class UserAdminModelView(ModelView):

    column_list = ['username', 'email', 'is_superuser']
    form_columns = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'constituency']
    form_extra_fields = {
        'password': PasswordField('Password'),
        'constituency': SelectField(
            'Constituency',
            coerce=int,
            choices=ConstituencyChoices(
                (0, "--- {} ---".format(_('no constituency')))
            )
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are methods on ModelView - create_form and edit_form, that can be overloaded and return form with right choices loaded from remote API. Look at the documentation https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.create_form and https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.edit_form .

```py
class UserAdminModelView(ModelView):

    column_list = ['username', 'email', 'is_superuser']
    form_columns = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'constituency']
    form_extra_fields = {
        'password': PasswordField('Password'),
        'constituency': SelectField('Constituency', coerce=int)
    }

    class ConstituencyChoices(Iterator):
        def __init__(self, constituencies, first_item=None):
            self.first_item = first_item
            self.constituencies = constituencies

        def __next__(self):
            if self.first_item is not None:
                res = self.first_item
                self.first_item = None
                return res
            constituency = self.constituencies.__next__()
            res = (constituency['id'], constituency['name'])
            return res

    def serve_constituency_choices(self):
        constituencies = (
            get_constituency(constituency_id) for constituency_id in get_constituencies()
        )
        return self.ConstituencyChoices(constituencies, (0, "-----"))

    def create_form(self, obj=None):
        form = super().create_form(obj=obj)
        form.constituency.choices = self.serve_constituency_choices()
        return form

    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        form = super().edit_form(obj=obj)
        form.constituency.choices = self.serve_constituency_choices()
        return form
```